# Running a Raspberry image with qemu-system-aarch64 having a systemd.run firstrun.sh script gets stuck

Tags: raspberry-pi, qemu

I'm trying to emulate a Raspberry Pi (+OS) with Qemu. I'd like the OS to execute a `firstrun.sh` script on boot to configure various things.

This is how I start qemu:

```
qemu-system-aarch64 \
    -M raspi3b \
    -cpu cortex-a53 \
    -m 1G \
    -kernel kernel8.img \
    -dtb bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb \
    -drive "file=2023-05-03-raspios-bullseye-arm64-lite.img,format=raw,index=0,media=disk" \
    -append "rw earlyprintk loglevel=8 console=ttyAMA0,115200 dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootdelay=1 systemd.run=/boot/firstrun.sh systemd.run_success_action=none debug systemd.unit=kernel-command-line.target" \
    -usb \
    -device usb-mouse \
    -device usb-kbd \
    -device usb-net,netdev=net0 \
    -nographic \
    -serial mon:stdio \
    -netdev user,id=net0,hostfwd=tcp::7777-:22
```

However, when configuring Qemu/the Kernel to execute a systemd script `systemd.run=/boot/firstrun.sh`, it gets stuck and won't continue booting.

The last lines that get printed are:

```
[  OK  ] Finished Command from Kernel Command Line.
[  OK  ] Reached target Command from Kernel Command Line
```

This is a minimal firstrun script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set +e
echo "This is the firstrun script"
rm -f /boot/firstrun.sh
sed -i 's| systemd.run.*||g' /boot/cmdline.txt
exit 0
```

To completely reproduce, these are the steps:

```
# Download image
wget https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_lite_arm64/images/raspios_lite_arm64-2023-05-03/2023-05-03-raspios-bullseye-arm64-lite.img.xz
xz --extract 2023-05-03-raspios-bullseye-arm64-lite.img.xz

# Setup image - extract kernel.img and copy firstrun script
mount_dir=/mnt/raspberrypi
free_loopdev="$(sudo losetup -f)"
sudo kpartx -a -v 2023-05-03-raspios-bullseye-arm64-lite.img
loop_mapper=/dev/mapper/$(basename "${free_loopdev}")
sudo mkdir -p "${mount_dir}"
sudo mount "${loop_mapper}p2" "${mount_dir}"
sudo mount "${loop_mapper}p1" "${mount_dir}/boot"
cp "${mount_dir}/boot/kernel8.img" .
cp "${mount_dir}/boot/bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb" .
sudo cp firstrun.sh "${mount_dir}/boot"

# Run Qemu with Image
cmdline="rw earlyprintk loglevel=8 console=ttyAMA0,115200 dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootdelay=1 systemd.run=/boot/firstrun.sh systemd.run_success_action=none debug systemd.unit=kernel-command-line.target"
qemu-img resize -f raw "2023-05-03-raspios-bullseye-arm64-lite.img" 4G
qemu-system-aarch64 \
    -M raspi3b \
    -cpu cortex-a53 \
    -m 1G \
    -kernel kernel8.img \
    -dtb bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb \
    -drive "file=2023-05-03-raspios-bullseye-arm64-lite.img,format=raw,index=0,media=disk" \
    -append "${cmdline}" \
    -usb \
    -device usb-mouse \
    -device usb-kbd \
    -device usb-net,netdev=net0 \
    -nographic \
    -serial mon:stdio \
    -netdev user,id=net0,hostfwd=tcp::7777-:22
```

If I omit the `firstrun.sh` script, boot process works fine.

Why won't boot process continue when executing firstrun.sh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By setting `systemd.run`, you are implicitly setting `systemd.unit=kernel-command-line.target` (in fact, in your command line you're setting that *explicitly*, but that's not necessary). Setting `systemd.unit` is effectively telling systemd, "do this **instead of** performing a normal boot".

That's why things appear to get "stuck" -- your firstrun script executes correctly, and as far as systemd is concerned nothing else needs to happen.

The simplest solution is probably to end your `firstrun.sh` script with:

```
systemctl start --no-block multi-user.target
```

This will continue with a regular boot after your firstrun script is complete.

---

Given a `firstrun.sh` script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -x

echo "enable ssh"
systemctl enable --now ssh

echo "set root password"
echo 'root:secret' | chpasswd

echo "continue boot"
systemctl start --no-block multi-user.target
```

I can successfully log in as `root` on the console when the system has finished booting. Ssh is active on host port 7777.

---

Unrelated to your question, but you can avoid use `kpartx` by using the `-P` argument to `losetup`:

```
loopdev="$(sudo losetup -fP --show)"
sudo mkdir -p "${mount_dir}"
sudo mount "${loopdev}p2" "${mount_dir}"
sudo mount "${loopdev}p1" "${mount_dir}/boot"
```

And you can avoid mucking about with loop devices and `sudo` completely by using `guestfish` to manipulate the image. I would do something like this to (a) create a copy-on-write clone of the original image and then (b) configure it:

```
#!/bin/bash

BASEIMAGE=2023-05-03-raspios-bullseye-arm64-lite.img

# Download image
if ! [ -f "$BASEIMAGE" ]; then
  wget https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_lite_arm64/images/raspios_lite_arm64-2023-05-03/2023-05-03-raspios-bullseye-arm64-lite.img.xz
  xz --extract 2023-05-03-raspios-bullseye-arm64-lite.img.xz
fi

echo "creating work image"
rm -f raspi-work.qcow2
qemu-img create -b "$BASEIMAGE" -F raw -f qcow2 raspi-work.qcow2 4G

echo "copying files"
guestfish -a raspi-work.qcow2 -m /dev/sda2:/ -m /dev/sda1:/boot <<EOF
copy-out /boot/kernel8.img .
copy-out /boot/bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb .
copy-in firstrun.sh /boot/
EOF

# ...remainder of script here...
```